# XML Response time ejabberd

Tags: java, android, xml, response, ejabberd

At the moment I'm trying to develop an Android Application for Instant Messaging. I want to use ejabberd for this on an Ubuntu Server. There is just one problem. 
When I try to connect to my ejabberd first with this xml-line:
`<stream:stream to='x.x.x.x' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>`
it takes very long to receive the answer (about 20 seconds, sometimes longer).
I just have this problem, when I send some "good" data to the Server. Sending some "bad" data, i receive the Error message very fast.

It's performed by an Android IntentService
I will Post my Code here too:
the attributes:

```
private Socket socket;
private String host = "x.x.x.x";
private int port = 5222;
private OutputStream out = null;
private String in = null;
```

the doInBackground():

```
this.socket = new Socket(host,port);
if(!this.socket.isConnected()){
        Log.e("Socket","Socket nicht geöffnet");
}else{
        Log.e("Socket","Socket erfolgreich geöffnet");

    //create output stream
    try {
            this.out = socket.getOutputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    //write to output stream
    StringBuffer stringbuffer = new StringBuffer();
    stringbuffer.append("<stream:stream to='5.175.8.41' xmlns='jabber:client' xmlns:stream='http://etherx.jabber.org/streams'>");

    //convert into bits and give it to outputstream
    try {
            this.out.write(String.valueOf(stringbuffer).getBytes("UTF-8"),0,String.valueOf(stringbuffer).getBytes().length);
            out.flush();
            Log.e("Connecting-out","Erstes Tupel erfolgreich gesendet.");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    //receive the answer from server
    try {
        Log.e("lol","lol");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream(),"UTF-8"),200);
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String aux;
    aux = in.readLine();


    this.in = builder.toString();
    Log.e("...",aux);



    } catch (IOException e) {

    e.printStackTrace();
    }

    Log.e("Connecting-in",in);
```

i think especially these lines

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    String aux;
    aux = in.readLine();


        this.in = builder.toString();
```

take very long. But the strange thing is , that the Error message is read very fast. So it has to be the Server?

Can someone please help me?
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Ok guys. Now I have installed the LATEST version of ejabberd (not the one provided by Ubuntu...I installed it with the .run from ejabberd.com itself) ... the problem keeps on existing, what mean that maybe its really my Code. Please some help. ANOTHER "HINT" was, that when I try to just read the first character of my BufferedReader he gives it to me instantly (its a "60" which representates "<" in ASCII ==> right character). But why is he giving me the whole string with such an delay??

Comment: Have you run a packet-capture on the conversation? Maybe when you send the good XML you're not sending everything over the wire that you think you are. You can also use pcap to view another Jabber client connecting and learn from what it sends.

Comment: I checked this out (Sorry I didn't try this earlier, but I'm pretty new to this "deep" layer of communication) The result is, that the whole data is sent and my ejabberd Server is responding pretty fast in 0.3 seconds. So it has to be sth. with my code.

Comment: I GOT IT! I will post the corrected Code soon :) But thanks for your effort. By the way: It really was the .readLine() ... I realised it with a CharBuffer and it worked!

Answer (score 1):

You used `readLine()` and it waits for new line character.

On error, server generally disconnects the connection.
It is why you get error answer immediately.

I suggest you not using `readLine()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply :) But like I commented, I got it without using readLine() . Now I use read(CharBuffer cb[], int offset, int length).

Comment: To find the problem, check the server first with a tool such as telnet. Probably server side doesn't have a problem. For android client, consider using library such as asmack. It handles complicated xmpp protocol.

Comment: This should not sound aggressive or offending now, even if you can read it like that (especially the tird part). First. thanks for your comment. :) Second: It works fine now, watch below (now I'm on the TLS Handshake). Third: NO! I dont want to use ASmack. I tried it and it worked. Of course I can use it now and understand NOTHING of the connection e.g. ..., to the Server, but I WANT to. My target was to learn sth. about servers communicating with clients over sockets, so I dont want to "understand how to use ASmack".